# How to link coordinate with pieces?

Tags: python

I want to make chess, but I confused with one question. How to link my chessboard and pieces? As chessboard can be list with pieces on it,

```
 chessboard = [(x, y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)]
```

Pawns:

```
pawns = []
for pawnY in range(8):
    pawn = (pawnY, 1)
    pawns.append(pawn)
```

Next I tried to replace coordinates. I just don't know what's the difference between following code, which give me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
[chessboard[chessboard.index(e)] = '♟' for i, e in enumerate(pawns) if e in chessboard]
```

and this, but this works:

```
 for i, e in enumerate(pawns):
     if e in chessboard:
         chessboard[chessboard.index(e)] = '♟'
```

Output:

```
 print(chessboard)
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4), (7, 4), (0, 5), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5), (0, 6), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 6), (7, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7)]
```

So, what should I do to link coordinates with piece and than operate them? Can you give me peace of advice?

Comment: You're getting a SyntaxError because you can't have an assignment statement inside a list comprehension. When you want to "link" two pieces of data together, try using a dictionary. (A bit vague, I know, which is why this is a comment and not an answer)

Comment: List comprehensions are used to make new lists. They cannot be used to assign values to existing lists as you are trying to do. While your second, working example may seem similar to the first, they are, in fact, quite different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are after exactly, but you seem to confuse the structure (all the x,y positions) of the chessboard with the content (pieces) of the chessboard.

Instead of storing 8*8 = 64 tuples with x,y positions in a list, you could create a nested (2D) list of lists to encode the structure of your board:

```
chessboard = [[0 for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]
```

resulting in the following `chessboard`:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now you can refer to every postion simply by its 2D index, e.g. `chessboard[0][0]` in the corner. I'm using `0` here to represent an empy square on the board.

You can then continue to fill it with pieces, e.g. pawns:

```
for pawnY in range(8):
    chessboard[1][pawnY] = '♟'
```

resulting in the updated `chessboard`:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟', '♟'],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

After filling your board with pieces at the starting positions, you can write functions to move pieces according to their respective rules.

Comment: Thanks, but how to get coordinate (x,y) of each piece and board cell, than operate them?

Comment: This representation encodes the entire state of the board at any turn. You would access a piece by its (x,y) coordinate instead of the other way around. e.g. in the updated board state above `chessboard[1][1]` would return `'♟'`. Once you access the value for a piece you can check the type, legal moves and make a move accordingly. Making a move would involve updating both the new position and updating the old position to an empty square.
e.g. move pawn from (1,1) to (2,1):
`>>> chessboard[2][1] = '♟'` 
`>>> chessboard[1][1] = 0` 
hope that helps!